# Error recovering data from rabbitmq mnesia

Tags: rabbitmq, recovery, mnesia

We've servers running rabbitmq 3.5.6 and it ran into disk full at one point.

The server has issue so we tried to copy the files from mnesia folder to another server that has rabbitmq as well. We changed what it requires on the new server to match the hostname from the previous one.

We tried this with files from couple of crashed servers and we're able to recover the queue messages.

But for some others it seems it's not able to do it and just hangs or frozen when I ran the service rabbitmq-server start command. Base on the rabbit@host.log it seems there're some parse segment issue maybe.

But it will have a line mentioning Restarting crashed queue 'clicks' in vhost '/'. and either took too long (don't know if it's stuck) or it will repeat some of the lines again and restarting crashed queue.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Here's the log we've from the server when it starts up...

```
=INFO REPORT==== 30-Sep-2016::16:45:15 ===
Starting RabbitMQ 3.5.6 on Erlang R14B04
Copyright (C) 2007-2015 Pivotal Software, Inc.
Licensed under the MPL. See http://www.rabbitmq.com/
=INFO REPORT==== 30-Sep-2016::16:45:15 ===
node : rabbit@mq-mt10
home dir : /var/lib/rabbitmq
config file(s) : /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
cookie hash : OHOm6cAi0pRByqTsrYdG1A==
log : /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@mq-mt10.log
sasl log : /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@mq-mt10-sasl.log
database dir : /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@mq-mt10
=INFO REPORT==== 30-Sep-2016::16:45:15 ===
Memory limit set to 12838MB of 16047MB total.
=INFO REPORT==== 30-Sep-2016::16:45:15 ===
Disk free limit set to 50MB
=INFO REPORT==== 30-Sep-2016::16:45:15 ===
Limiting to approx 924 file handles (829 sockets)
=INFO REPORT==== 30-Sep-2016::16:45:15 ===
FHC read buffering: ON
FHC write buffering: ON
=INFO REPORT==== 30-Sep-2016::16:45:16 ===
Priority queues enabled, real BQ is rabbit_variable_queue
=INFO REPORT==== 30-Sep-2016::16:45:16 ===
Management plugin: using rates mode 'basic'
=INFO REPORT==== 30-Sep-2016::16:45:16 ===
msg_store_transient: using rabbit_msg_store_ets_index to provide index
=INFO REPORT==== 30-Sep-2016::16:45:16 ===
msg_store_persistent: using rabbit_msg_store_ets_index to provide index
=ERROR REPORT==== 30-Sep-2016::16:45:18 ===
** Generic server <0.240.0> terminating
** Last message in was {init,{<0.159.0>,[non_clean_shutdown]}}
** When Server state == {q,{amqqueue,
{resource,<<"/">>,queue,<<"clicks">>},
true,false,none,[],<0.240.0>,[],[],[],
undefined,[],undefined,live},
none,false,undefined,undefined,
{state,
{queue,[],[],0},
{active,1475268316149018,1.0}},
undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
{state,fine,5000,undefined},
{0,nil},
undefined,undefined,undefined,
{state,
{dict,0,16,16,8,80,48,
{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
[],[]},
{{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
[],[],[]}}},
delegate},
undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,0,running}
** Reason for termination ==
** {function_clause,
[{rabbit_queue_index,parse_segment_entries,
[<<"y">>,false,
{{array,16384,0,undefined,
{{{{{{{true,
<<6,79,246,149,241,55,30,251,55,72,30,36,11,132,
161,214,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,167>>,
<<131,104,6,100,0,13,98,97,115,105,99,95,109,101,
115,115,97,103,101,104,4,100,0,8,114,101,115,
111,117,114,99,101,109,0,0,0,1,47,100,0,8,101,
120,99,104,97,110,103,101,109,0,0,0,0,108,0,0,0,
1,109,0,0,0,6,99,108,105,99,107,115,106,104,6,
100,0,7,99,111,110,116,101,110,116,97,60,100,0,
4,110,111,110,101,109,0,0,0,3,16,0,2,100,0,25,
114,97,98,98,105,116,95,102,114,97,109,105,110,
103,95,97,109,113,112,95,48,95,57,95,49,108,0,0,
0,1,109,0,0,4,167,123,34,64,118,101,114,115,105,
111,110,34,58,34,49,34,44,34,64,116,105,109,101,
115,116,97,109,112,34,58,34,50,48,49,54,45,48,
57,45,50,57,84,49,48,58,48,57,58,50,56,46,54,49,
56,90,34,44,34,98,101,97,116,34,58,123,34,104,
111,115,116,110,97,109,101,34,58,34,105,112,45,
49,48,45,50,53,50,45,50,45,49,48,48,34,44,34,
110,97,109,101,34,58,34,105,112,45,49,48,45,50,
53,50,45,50,45,49,48,48,34,125,44,34,115,111,
117,114,99,101,34,58,34,47,118,97,114,47,108,
111,103,47,102,105,108,101,98,101,97,116,47,114,
97,98,98,105,116,109,113,95,99,108,105,99,107,
115,47,102,105,108,101,98,101,97,116,46,106,115,
111,110,34,44,34,116,121,112,101,34,58,34,108,
111,103,34,44,34,104,111,115,116,34,58,34,105,
.
.
.
                          50,56,46,57,54,52,55,125,44,34,108,111,103,116,
                          121,112,101,34,58,34,67,108,105,99,107,79,114,
                          69,114,114,111,114,34,125,106,109,0,0,0,16,209,
                          241,202,203,147,189,214,158,240,46,46,46>>},
                    del,no_ack},
                   undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
                   undefined},
                  10,10},
                 100,100,100,100,100,100,100},
                1000,1000,1000,1000},
               10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000}},
          16384}]},
    {rabbit_queue_index,recover_segment,3},
    {rabbit_queue_index,'-init_dirty/3-fun-0-',5},
    {lists,foldl,3},
    {rabbit_queue_index,init_dirty,3},
    {rabbit_variable_queue,init,6},
    {rabbit_priority_queue,init,3},
    {rabbit_amqqueue_process,init_it2,3}]}
=ERROR REPORT==== 30-Sep-2016::16:49:54 ===
Restarting crashed queue 'clicks' in vhost '/'.
```

Comment: We found this tool that is able to read the rabbitmq queue idx files and persistent store rdq files. We were able to then re-import that data back into rabbitmq one message at a time and let our consumers process the data normally.

https://github.com/jeffbryner/rdqdump

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We found this tool that is able to read the rabbitmq queue idx files and persistent store rdq files. We were able to then re-import that data back into rabbitmq one message at a time and let our consumers process the data normally.

https://github.com/jeffbryner/rdqdump

Comment: This worked great for me. I even submitted a pull request updating it to the newest version of python. Hope it helps someone out there!

Comment: @SamMarion I have large rdq files to parse but unfortunately it isn't working for me. I am not able to get proper jsons out of it. Can you share your working PR? It will be of huge help.